# how to get the data using from date and to date in sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to retreive data from database with the condition from date to to date using between query,

my query is,

```
select * from Master where Date between '01-08-2013' and '30-08-2013'
```

but it retreive all data from the table...

i need only data with in that date..

i tried another one like,

```
select * from PatientMaster where EntryDate >= '01-08-2013' and EntryDate<= '30-08-2013'
```

how its posible..

whats wrong with my query...

sorry im very bad in english...

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

A date string has the syntax `YYYY-MM-DD` and not `DD-MM-YYYY`

```
select * from Master 
where `Date` between '2013-08-01' and '2013-08-30'
```

Comment: Oh - that is not good. Please always store dates as date and not as string. It would be wise to change the data type.

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use

```
select * from Master where Date >='01-08-2013' and dateadd(dd,1,'30-08-2013')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your strings to dates.  [This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) shows you how to do it in mysql, which is what you have tagged.  For sql server, which is in your subject line, use [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Then you do a slight modification of your 2nd attempt.  Instead of

```
and EntryDate <= the end date
```

you want

```
and EntryDate < the day after the end date
```

That takes care of any time components.  It might not matter in your case, but it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking for an query that works with your format? (dd-mm-yy)
CAST to the desired format!

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

105 = dd-mm-yy

```
SELECT * FROM Master
```

WHERE CONVERT(date, Date, 105) BETWEEN '01-08-13' and '30-08-13'

Be conscious with regards of the choice of data type for date Columns, 
with or without time, day or year first etc. and please do not use varchar 
for dates...
know that it CAN be confusing to call a date column for only Date...
be consistent with high/lower case.